# Виртуальный базовый класс

Tags: классы, c++

Добрый день!

Возник вопрос: Как явно определить список инициализации для такого класса Derived?

```
struct Base
{};
struct Der: virtual Base
{};
struct Derived: Der, Base
{};

int main()
{
}
```

Т.е. в конструкторе Derived нужно инициализировать 3 класса: сначала виртуальный Base1 (из части Der), затем Der (с игнорированием его виртуальной части Base), и затем прямой базовый класс Base.
Если инициализировать по умолчанию, то компилит нормально (по крайней мере, ideone). Но если попытаться инициализировать явно, например, как-то так

```
struct Derived: Der, Base
{
    Derived():Base(),Derived(),Base(){}
};
```

, то начинает ругаться. Можно ли как-то все это инициализировать? С конструкторами по умолчанию первый вариант прокатывает, а вот если у Base конструктор будет с аргументами, то уже становится непонятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инициализировать получилось как-то так.

```
struct Base
{
    Base() {cerr<<"Base"<<endl;}
};
struct Der : virtual Base 
{
    Der() {cerr<<"Der"<<endl;}
};
struct Derived : Der,virtual Base
{
    Derived() : Base(),Der() {cerr<<"Derived"<<endl;}
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cerr<<"Creating Derived"<<endl;
    Derived c;
    return 0; 
}
```

Кусок кода выше скомпилировался на gcc 4.8.1 20130909. Вывод :

Creating Derived

Base

Der

Derived

Comment: Это да, потому что Derived в таком случае имеет один экземпляр Base, и неоднозначностей в списке инициализации на возникает. Но что делать, если Derived наследует Base не виртуально? Тогда в конструкторе нужно будет инициализировать Base 2 раза (один виртуальный и один прямой базовый), и здесь уже непонятно, как это сделать.  
P.S. на практике это не понадобится, вопрос чисто академический

Comment: Eсли Derived наследует Base не виртуально, то по идее не получится. Правда, если наследовать Der от Base не виртуально, то тогда можно "нормально" инициализировать Base. Только тогда он будет создан два раза, и обращение к его методам будет неоднозначным.